# Error Data is Null in Asp.net core using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to get data from my stored procedures

Here's my Controller
[DashboardController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSUWY.png)

Here's my ViewModel [DashboardViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fst4G.png)

Here's my Javascript [AJAXPhoto1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm7fw.png) [AJAXPhoto2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgf6B.png)

Here's my table [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXLM.png)

getting an error of **SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values**

Note: my stored procedure is displaying values when executed from sql only not in the asp.net core

im still new to asp.net core and first time using stored procedure without entity framework. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please input code here, instead of screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should be caused by the existence of a `null value` in the table in the database.

The `DateTime` type in your `ViewModel` does not allow null values, it's `[Required]` by default. However, since the attribute may have a null value in your database, so you need to change your `DateTime` type to nullable type like following.

```
 public DateTime? DateStarted{ get; set; }
 public DateTime? DateCompleted{ get; set; }
 public DateTime? DueDate{ get; set; }
```

Comment: woahhh that might be the problem it is now fixed thanks! I didn't think about it haha thank you so much!